# Spartacus-storefront| After scrolling down list of results and then clicking on a product, when returning to the results it should remember position

Tags: scrollview, spartacus-storefront

In Spartacus-storefront, when scrolling through the search page products and goes to PDP or product page after accessing/clicking any random product and come back to the search page via browser back functionality the search page scroll position is not the same as when accessed the product/PDP. The same issue is present in the demo site as well ( https://spartacus-demo.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com/electronics-spa/en/USD/).

Comment: What stack (OS, Browser, version) are you using? I tested this scenario just now on WIndows 10 
- Firefox (87.0) it works proper.
- Chrome (89.0.4389.114) and Edge (89.0.774.76) I can see that after srcoll, while open PDP I can see that page is scrolled down, but while click back I'm in the same position on search page. If I do scrolling up on PDP and back, search page is also scrolled up. It looks like there is problem with independency of scroll position for those pages in chromium based browsers.
It looks like we have created ticket already: https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/issues/10143

Comment: Thanks for the response, Michal. I am using  Window 10 as OS and Goggle chrome browser(Version 90.0.4430.85 (Official Build) (64-bit))